# sequel check if record exists with multilpe filters

Tags: ruby, database, orm, sequel

I have records of gallery with this columns:

```
id gallery_origin file_name ...
```

For records whose `gallery_origin` is `X`, I want to check whether their `file_name` is `blank?`.

I am trying to check if in column is already a present value, but just in case when is another column matched.

I think it is stupid to select all records for particular gallery_origin and check it. Maybe sequel can do this.

Some way like this?

```
if GalleryData.where((:gallery_origin => :id) & (:file_name => params[:file])).blank?
...
```

But this is not working, is there any sequel trick to do this?

Comment: What is your ORM? is it ActiveRecord?

Comment: They have already said: Sequel.

Comment: @Mlok Did you try `GalleryData.where(:gallery_origin => id, :file_name => params[:file]).blank?`

Comment: actually, this `GalleryData.where{(:gallery_origin => :id) & (:file_name => params[:file])}`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Sequel but this Cheatsheet has some example that could help I guess http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html#top

Comment: @aBadAssCowboy ha cool, I was thinking so complicated and used syntax for models, this works pretty well, I didnt have an idea I was thinking it is able to do AND OR etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution, it works pretty well, my thinking was much more focused on sql so I tried to do AND, OR etc, but simply "," works fine.

@Mlok Did you try GalleryData.where(:gallery_origin => id, :file_name => params[:file]).blank? – aBadAssCowboy

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how this answers your question? How is checking `where(..., file_name: params[:file]).blank?` equivalent to checking whether the file name is blank?! Surely you'd need to do: `where(..., file_name: ["", nil])`?

Comment: File name here is in params sent by form in padrino form helper to the route in controller, so in params[:file] is string of the name of the file and I have `if not` at the beginning to reverse condition.